# "Unable to launch event" error opening calendar events (*.ics) on android phones

Tags: android, events, calendar, icalendar

I get the error "Unable to launch event" if I try to open an *.ics event file on Android.  It only works if opening directly from gmail.  Any other attempts to open it outside of gmail gives the above error.  I am attempting to send calendar events over text messages.  It works for iphones, but I get this error on android phones.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. If this is a programming question, please provide the [mcve] of how you are trying to "open" this file.